# Docky graphical problems

Tags: nvidia, intel, docky

Docky displays a blue bar(sometimes solid white) near the edges, and when hiding. Screenshots attached.
This happens randomly, usually after a suspend, but not always. I've noticed this doesn't happen when I use my Nvidia card(gt740m). So it might be an issue specific to the Intel HD 4600 card.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could add the output of `sudo lshw -c display` to the question. It seems to me to be specific case, so it will be more helpful and easily referenced.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be resolved by enabling the SNA acceleration option instead of UXA.

Comment: It will be better if you add a reference